# Calabash-android did not find adb.exe

Tags: android, ruby, calabash, calabash-android

WARN: Did not find 'adb.exe' in any standard directory of 'C:\Program Files\And
roid\android-sdk\platform-tools'. Calabash will therefore take longer to load
 WARN: Did not find 'aapt.exe' in any standard directory of 'C:\Program Files\An
droid\android-sdk\platform-tools'. Calabash will therefore take longer to load
 WARN: Did not find 'zipalign.exe' in any standard directory of 'C:\Program File
s\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools'. Calabash will therefore take longer to lo
ad
ERROR: Could not locate Android dependency
ERROR: You can read about how Calabash is searching for an Android SDK and how y
ou can help here:
ERROR: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/documentation/in
stallation.md#prerequisites
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/lib/calabash-android/d
ependencies.rb:234:in `locate_android_dependencies': Could not find 'aapt.exe' i
n 'C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools' (Calabash::Android::Envi
ronment::InvalidEnvironmentError)
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/lib/calab
ash-android/dependencies.rb:125:in`setup'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/lib/calab
ash-android/dependencies.rb:25:in `android_dependencies'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/lib/calab
ash-android/dependencies.rb:65:in`aapt_path'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/lib/calab
ash-android/helpers.rb:124:in `unsign_apk'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/lib/calab
ash-android/helpers.rb:117:in`block in resign_apk'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tmpdir.rb:89:in `mktmpdir'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/lib/calab
ash-android/helpers.rb:112:in`resign_apk'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/bin/calab
ash-android:127:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23/bin/calabash-android:23:in`load'
        from C:/Ruby23/bin/calabash-android:23:in `'

**After upgrading ruby version to 2.3. I got this error. I have done the setting regarding path but still it is not working.**

Comment: I think that version might not be supported. I have been using ruby 2.0.0 for some time, based on some info some where about not to go beyond. And I can see that Xamarin recommends 2.1 on their page https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/configuring/osx/

Comment: what is the value of $ANDROID_HOME?

Answer (score 0):

create a user environment variable **ANDROID_HOME** and point it to
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\ dont put platform-tools in this path. If you're using Android studio it might be in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

you'll need to make one for jdk as well make sure you have jdk installed and create a **JAVA_HOME** environment variable and point it to your installation directory, for example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101 (note this is not jre but jdk)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use [Cygwin + RVM](http://blog.developwithpassion.com/2012/03/30/installing-rvm-with-cygwin-on-windows/) to manage your ruby version, I had several problems with one click installer and cmd/powershell for Windows. Calabash works better with *NIX like terminals even if it is an emulated one. Also remember to export ANDROID_HOME variable pointing to your Android SDK installation directory before running your scripts.